# 'native' vs. 'qgis' geoprocessing algorithm provider in (Py)QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

In QGIS 3 processing toolbox among all the algorithms with the QGIS 3 icon there are some with **Algorithm-ID** starting with *qgis:* and some starting with *native:*.

What is the difference between processing algorithm providers *qgis* and *native*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, the bit before the colon is the provider name, in this case 'native' ([can see the code for this here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/processing/qgsprocessingalgorithm.cpp#L44)).

From what I can tell, the processing algorithms named native have been ported to C++ (they were written in Python in previous versions). This has the obvious advantage of speed and is why some algorithms are considerably faster in 3.x

There seems to be a [list of them here on Github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsnativealgorithms.cpp) in QgsNativeAlgorithms::loadAlgorithms() where they get loaded.

Comment: So the `qgis` providers refer to "slow" Python algorithms?

Comment: In my understanding (and experience): No, to *fast* Python algorithms. But 'native' provider refer *much faster* c++ algorithms.